# Scipy Optimization: how to find more solutions

Tags: python

Why I obtain just one solution from this problem? I should get two solutions. I want to minimize the following function: here`f(x,y)=xy subject to the equality constraint: exp(x^2 + y^2) =3.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x[0]*x[1]

def eq_cons(x):
    return np.exp(x[0]**2+x[1]**2)-3

bounds_x1 = (-100, 100)
bounds_x2 = (-100, 100)
bounds = [bounds_x1, bounds_x2]

constraint1 = {'type':'eq', 'fun':eq_cons}

x0 = [-1, -1]

res = minimize(f, x0, method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bounds, constraints = constraint1)

print(res)
```

```
     fun: 0.5493061443594626
     jac: array([-0.7411519 , -0.74115191])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 18
     nit: 6
    njev: 6
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([-0.74115191, -0.7411519 ])
```

Comment: You'll likely get the second solution if your starting parameters are closer to that solution.

Comment: Exactly, most optimization problems are very sensitive to the initial guess. Can you make an educated guess other than `[-1,-1]`? If not run your optimization multiple times with randomly generated `x0` values within your expected solution range